# Creating class constructor in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it good coding methodology to create a class in a loop? That is I am calling my DB to retrieve all the contacts, during this loop I am creating the contacts class based on the contact id (which again calls DB to retrieve the contact details based on id). Is this smart coding or wasteful resources?

```
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {
    Contact contact = new Contact(Convert.ToInt32(reader["contactid"]));
    userString = userString + contact.getSurname();
}
```

```
public Contact(int id) {
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Global.conn);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    string sql = "SELECT * 
                    FROM contact 
                  WHERE contactid=@contactid";
    command.CommandText = sql;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactid", id);
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) {
        FirstName = reader["name"].ToString();
        Surname = reader["Surname"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with that. Why are you opening a new connection and re-reading the contact though?

Comment: A bit of naming info: You're not creating a class in a loop; you're creating an object in a loop, which is an instance of the class. You should get all of the data needed for the `Contact` object while you're reading and pass it to your instance via the constructor or via an [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer).

Comment: Seems a bit strange to me. I would create a single query that selects all the contact information instead of the nested reader approach.

Comment: thanks. The issues that I have is that I have mapping tables throughout. So a contact can have multiple contact phones. This means from a DB perspective there is a mapping_contact_phone table that has a 1 to many relationship with the phone table. So a single query doesn't work for me as I get multiple rows. Was thinking to get the ID of the contact, call the constructor and then in there run multiple separate data reads to build the class variables. Just concerned about performance as a result.

Comment: If you could use an ORM such as entity framework (or a micro-ORM such as Dapper) it would make your life much easier.

Comment: Running a bunch of queries against SQL server like this is extremely costly - get everything you need using one query/reader.

Comment: It's inefficient this way. I intend to create a class of contact, iterate the rows and initiate a new contact when one doesn't exist (unique contact id). Then this contact class will link to a phone class and I can add more phones to this class. The result is that a each single contact will have multiple classes of phones etc. I do this by creating a list of contacts : List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>(); and then add a new contact: contacts.Add(new Contact(Id)); Is there a way to see if the contact was already created? If not create and if yes get the instance of the created one?

Comment: This is what I did :             List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Contact current = contacts.Find(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(reader["contactid"]));
                if (current is null)
                {
                    current = new Contact(Convert.ToInt32(reader["contactid"]));
                    contacts.Add(current);
                }
                current.Surname = reader["Surname"].ToString();
                current.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["contactid"]);
            }